# Performance Problems with DAX expression

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having a huge problem with performance in the below DAX measure.

```
Amount = CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        'Financial All Scenarios',
        IF (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Report Options'[Currency], "CD" ) = "USD",
            'Financial All Scenarios'[GLAmountUSD],
            IF (SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Report Options'[Currency], "CD" ) = "CD",
                'Financial All Scenarios'[GLAmountCD],
                'Financial All Scenarios'[GlAmountDoc]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This DAX measure does has the following.  There is a disconnected filter table called Report Options, which has 3 a field called Currency with 3 values in it CD, USD, and DOC.  This slicer is used to control which field is summed up from the fact table Financial All Scenarios.  If nothing is selected from the Report Options table it defaults to CD.

I have a report that has a bunch of data on it and it returns in a second when I have the Currency Report Option slicer on the report, but nothing selected.  As soon as I select the CD option it is spinning forever and not returning.

How can I adjust this DAX measure so that it performs well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterative functions tend to be expensive. How about refactoring like this?

```
Amount =
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Report Options'[Currency], "CD" ),
    "USD", SUM ( 'Financial All Scenarios'[GLAmountUSD] ),
    "CD", SUM ( 'Financial All Scenarios'[GLAmountCD] ),
    SUM ( 'Financial All Scenarios'[GlAmountDoc] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks that appears to work well.  I will have to read a little more to understand the difference between them from a Power BI standpoint.  I get what they both do, but just in how the actually work.

Comment: The basic aggregation functions like `SUM` can do a lot of optimization behind the scenes. Using `SUMX` forces it to instantiate a physical table and iterate through every single row and run through the `IF` logic every single row. Even without behind the scenes optimization, the way I wrote it you only have to do the switching logic once.